# What is happening in the code of this quicksort?

Tags: java, quicksort

I've found this code implementation for quick sort I wanted to ask: What is the bolded part doing in the code? Is checking if there are unsorted elements in the left and the right part of the array?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuickSort {
    static int a[];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("n = ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Array: ");
        a = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        quickSort(0, n - 1);

        System.out.println("Sorted array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }

        sc.close();

    }

    private static void quickSort(int left, int right) {
        int i = left, j = right;

        int pivot = a[(left + right) / 2];

        while (i <= j) {
            while (a[i] < pivot) {
                i++;
            }

            while (a[j] > pivot) {
                j--;
            }

            if (i <= j) {
                swap(a, i, j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }

        if (left < j) {
            quickSort(left, j);
        }

        if (i < right) {
            quickSort(i, right);
        }
    }

    private static void swap(int a[], int index1, int index2) {
        int aux = a[index1];
        a[index1] = a[index2];
        a[index2] = aux;
    }
}
```

I've tried to understand what is the code doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is checking if there are unsorted elements in the left and the right part of the array?

**Yes, it is!**

It is responsible for recursively calling the `quickSort` function on the left and right partitions of the array.

After the initial partitioning of the array into two sub-arrays (left and right), the `quickSort` function is called on each of these sub-arrays to further sort them. This process continues recursively until the sub-arrays become single elements or empty, at which point the sorting is complete.

So, the bolded code block essentially checks if there are still unsorted elements in the left and right sub-arrays and recursively applies the `quickSort` function to sort those sub-arrays. This recursive process is what eventually sorts the entire array in ascending order.